# Python: Dynamically add a word to a Regex which finds phone number from text?

Tags: python, regex

I have to differentiate **tel:919443177747**, **fax=919976384999** from a huge text. The word can be of any pattern as below.

contact_text_pattern =["sale","call","inquiry","inquiries","caller","enquiries","enquiry","tel"]

Kindly help me to change my regex such that it will be able to collect only the numbers that has any of the above keywords along with them.

Below is my regex:

> phones = re.findall(r'+?[0-9]{7,11}',text)

I have written a loop to substitute each word. But I'm not able to proceed. Please share your comments.

```
phone_word = re.findall(r("+'|'.join(self.contact_merged_list)+r"))",text) #find whether any of our keywords are in the text         
for word in phone_word:
        **Regex would help**
```

Comment: Replace `r("+'|'.join(self.contact_merged_list)+r"))"` with `r"\b({})\s*:\s*(\d{{7,11}})\b".format("|".join(self.contact_merged_list))"`

Comment: Sorry Wiktor, It didn't work.

Comment: Aha, your numbers contain more than `11` digits. See https://ideone.com/pDDMiL

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. But, Will that be able to find phone number as well ? I checked the linked which you sent. I thought **phone_word = re.findall(r"\b({})\s*:\s*(\d{{7,}})\b".format("|".join(contact_merged_list)),text)** will find only the words that match with contact_merged_text in the "text". Please correct me if I'm worng. Thank you

Comment: Do you see the result at the bottom? `('tel', '919443177747')`? The capturing group around `\d{7,}` ensures the number is returned within a tuple.

Comment: Yes I can see. Oh, then My text must be wrong. My text is the webpage content. I used beautifulsoup to convert the html to text. So my text is something like " helloworldtel:91944317747takecare"

Comment: Then remove `\b` from the regex, and that is all there is to it.

Comment: Okay I shall check now and Let you know. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm sorry Wiktor. I executed the code.                                                  `import re
contact_merged_list = ["sale","call","inquiry","inquiries","caller","enquiries","enquiry","tel"] 
text = 'hellotel:919443177747fax=919976384999'
phone_word = re.findall(r"({})\s*:\s*(\d{{7,}})\b".format("|".join(contact_merged_list)),text)
print phone_word
for word in phone_word:
 print(word)`  but I'm able to get an empty list.

Comment: You did not remove all `\b`s.

Comment: Great.. I'm sorry. I removed one of the \b and not the another. It worked Wiktor. thanks so much :)

Comment: The regex works Wiktor. I should also collect tel:+919443177747. Should I add a + operator in the regex ?

Comment: I added `phone_word = re.findall(r"({})\s*:\s*/+|(\d{{7,11}})".format("|".join(self.contact_merged_list)),text)`. It collects some junk numbers along with it. The output is [('', '504494011'), ('', '6563323255'), ('', '18003323370'), ('', '6565471975'), ('', '6563323255'), ('', '6563323255'), ('', '6563323255'), ('', '6563323255'), ('', '6563323133'), ('', '6563323233'), ('', '6563323255'), ('', '6563393583'), ('', '6563323255'), ('', '6563323255')] where 50449401 is some number in that paragraph. Also, the keyword is missing. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: The : and + are optional. I found that some text doesn't have tel:number format and some have tel+65number. So How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: I resolved by removing punctuators from the text and now its able to grab the values.

Comment: I suggest you add all these details to the question in a compact way.

Comment: Sure.. I just added the issues one after the other

Answer (score 0):

Better than regex would be to use a package that can intelligentally recognize, parse and format international phone numbers. There is a python port of the Google library, called [phonenumbers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers) ([github](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers))

Here's an example from the documentation

```
import phonenumbers
text = "Call me at 510-748-8230 if it's before 9:30, or on 703-4800500 after 10am."
for match in phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher(text, "US"):
    print match

> PhoneNumberMatch [11,23) 510-748-8230
> PhoneNumberMatch [51,62) 703-4800500

 for match in phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher(text, "US"):
    print phonenumbers.format_number(match.number, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)

> +15107488230
> +17034800500
```

Comment: But I'm not aware of the country code. There are possibilities of numbers from different country. Let me check the Google Library. Thanks :) Philshem